# Converting a NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert a `NSString` into a `NSDate` as shown below.

The value of `NSString *startTime` is **2015-06-23T01:37:53Z**,
 
but the value of `NSDate *startTimeDate` is **nil**. What is wrong with the code ?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *startTimeDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startTime];
```

Comment: Just remove `.SSS` from your format. I hope then it would working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your date format

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```

change into

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

**Swift**

check your date format

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

change into

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Do not quote the `Z` in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

The startTime you've specified doesn't have any milliseconds, so you want to use a dateFormat of:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

If you want to support both styles of XML date strings then I recommend creating two NSDateFormatter instances for both date formats, and try the other if you get nil from the first.

Comment: This is incorrect. Do not quote the `Z` in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 issues with your date format:

- `.SSS` is used to read milliseconds but variable `startTime` doesn't contains milliseconds value;
- `Z` represent **GMT** time zone and must not be escaped in dateFormat string.

Let's try to fix this ussues:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *startTimeDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startTime];
```

---

I recommend to use this [NSDateFormatter date formatting table](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/). It's very comprehensive and helpful.

Comment: The only answer to correctly identify the issues and properly handle the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple one, converting `NSString` to `NSDate` we use `NSDateformatter` using `dateFromString` method. We need to provide the `NSDateFormatter` style with existing style for `NSString`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-02-01T06:25:47Z"];
NSTimeZone *pdt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:pdt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"K:mm a, z"];
NSString * updated String = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: @AshishKakkad you actually messed this persons answer up slightly I have corrected. `Bhumika` there is still a typo on the bottom line though.

Comment: @AshishKakkad It wasn't a huge issue just a typo in my opinion they happen. Happy coding.